# Searching a SQLite3 table for a specific row OR is it faster to use Python

Tags: python, sql, algorithm, sqlite

What would be faster; searching a sqlite3 database table for a row whose primary key equals a specific string

**OR**

In Python, I obtain all the primary keys from a sqlite3 database table (using a query) as a Python list and use Pythons **in** keyword to test whether a specific string occurs within that list.

**I guess I am asking does SQLite3 employ a more advanced algorithm to find a specific row with the primary key I am searching for or would it be faster to just get all the primary keys myself & search using python(or employ my own Binary search once I get them all)?**

Code to do either way:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("d.db")
cur = conn.cursor()
isPresent = cur.execute( "SELECT target FROM stringList WHERE target='specificString';" ).fetchall()
return isPresent == None

// Alternate
primaryKeyList = cur.execute( "SELECT target FROM stringList;" ).fetchall()
return 'specificString' in primaryKeyList 

// Or I can sort the list then use a binary search or other fast algorithm
primaryKeyList = cur.execute( "SELECT target FROM stringList;" ).fetchall()
//..sort primaryKeyList
primaryKeyList = sortList(primaryKeyList)
return binarySearch('specificString') == True
```

*PS: Is there a way to tell SQLite3 in what order I want the rows to be stored in? So I can always have my rows in a table sorted alphabetically (according to their primary key)?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to every "would it be faster?" question is "test it yourself".

That said, the answer is that SQLite searching on an index is going to be faster than a SQLite table-scan plus an O(N) scan in Python.

As for your "tell SQLite how to store the rows" bit, you don't want that. You can do an `ORDER BY` to retrieve the results in a certain order - the way they're *stored* is an implementation detail.

Comment: Hmm, not sure a SQLite table scan would be that intensive: 1. For myself theres only 3 tables so it should not be too intensive. 2. If I store the position of table X in the header then open the file/database then move to that position using fseek()(C++) I can get there in no time with little effort. I dont understand how SQLite formats it files but I would image table lookups would involve this method. Are you sure that table-scans are really that memory intensive?

Comment: @JakeM: I didn't say the SQLite scan would be time-consuming nor memory-intensive. It won't be. It'll just be more expensive than looking up *one single row* from an index. Re: `fseek`ing in the SQLite file: don't. Really, don't. The SQLite people are mad good at their job of doing the micro-optimizations for you, and you should never consider doing something like that before you know you need it.

Comment: Listen to Borealid. Just use an Index for Row Lookup.